# How to send data from two inputs using button

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the HTML I currently have:

```html
<div class="location">
   <div class="first-line">
       <i id="Icon1" class="fas fa-map-marker"></i>
       <input class="location-input" placeholder="Miejscowość lub kod pocztowy">
       <div class="vertical-line"></div>
       <p class="gps-button"><i id="Icon2" class="fas fa-map-marker"></i></p>
   </div>
   <div class="second-line">
       <input class="zakres-input" placeholder="Promień wyszukiwań (km)">
   </div>
       <button class="fm-button" type="submit">Znajdz Mecz</button>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to get values from both inputs. I have to send them later to my backend using the FetchApi.
I am pretty new to JavaScript and don't really know how to handle it ( I know how to use `fetch`, but not how to get the inputs ). Is it even possible that one button will submit this, or do I have to get this data separately from the inputs. Here is what I tried to do:

```js
const search1 = document.querySelector('input[placeholder="Miejscowość lub kod pocztowy"]');
const search2 = document.querySelector('input[placeholder="Promień wyszukiwań (km)"]');
const button = document.querySelector('button[class="fm-button"]');


button.addEventListener("click", function(){

    const data1 = {search1: this.value};
    const data2 = {search2: this.value};
    //alert("data1");
    //console.log(data1);

});
```

Comment: Please include your API call so we can get an idea of where you're at with that piece too.

Comment: Instead of listening to button onclick event, you should put your inputs and buttons in between a form HTML tag. Then you should listen for onSubmit event for this form. You can reach each form input and their values using event handler function's `event` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value from an input element by accessing its `value` attribute.

So in this case `search1.value` and `search2.value`

```js
const search1 = document.querySelector('input[placeholder="Miejscowość lub kod pocztowy"]');
const search2 = document.querySelector('input[placeholder="Promień wyszukiwań (km)"]');
const button = document.querySelector('button[class="fm-button"]');


button.addEventListener("click", function(){

    //Don't run anything if any of the values are undefined
    if(!search1.value || !search2.value) return

    //Now we collect our data
    const data = {data1: search1.value, data2: search2.value}
    
    //Then we can send out a post request example with axios,
    //but any method of sending requests will work
    axios.post("https://placeholder.com/myendpoint", data)
    .then((res) =>{
        //Log the response 
        console.log(res.data)
    })
    .catch((err) =>{
        //Throw error if there's an error
        if(err) throw err
    })

});
```

I'd for sure recommend axios over the fetchApi.

Answer (score 1):

Inside of a DOM event handler, `this` refers to the DOM object that fired the event. In your case, that's the `button`, so trying to get `this.value`, gets the `button` value, not the `input` elements.

Also, because you're storing the `value`s in `object`s, you need to access the property of the object that has the data.

```js
const search1 = document.querySelector('input[placeholder="Miejscowość lub kod pocztowy"]');
const search2 = document.querySelector('input[placeholder="Promień wyszukiwań (km)"]');
const button = document.querySelector('button[class="fm-button"]');

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // Don't get "this".value (which is the button)
    // Get the value from the DOM objects (the input elements)
    const data1 = {search1: search1.value};
    const data2 = {search2: search2.value};
    
    // Access the data via the object property you stored it in
    console.log(data1.search1, data2.search2);
});
```

```html
<div class="location">
   <div class="first-line">
       <i id="Icon1" class="fas fa-map-marker"></i>
       <input class="location-input" placeholder="Miejscowość lub kod pocztowy">
       <div class="vertical-line"></div>
       <p class="gps-button"><i id="Icon2" class="fas fa-map-marker"></i></p>
   </div>
   <div class="second-line">
       <input class="zakres-input" placeholder="Promień wyszukiwań (km)">
   </div>
       <button class="fm-button" type="submit">Znajdz Mecz</button>
</div>
```